# Additional information needed in summarise(nAlive = n())?

Tags: r

this is my first post and I am fairly new to R so please have patience and ask for any other info needed. I will be as thorough as I can.

So, I have a question about this set of code

```
Alive<- JulyData%>%
    filter(!is.na(Lice))%>%
    group_by(Cage, Species)%>%
summarise(nAlive=n())
```

Do I need to include anything in the line `summarise(nAlive = n())` or is this perfectly acceptable? The `n()` seems like it is lacking something but I am not sure.

I am trying to count the number of alive specimens grouped by cage and species.

Here is the full code I am working with for reference:

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
library(car)
library(emmeans)

JulyData<- read_excel("~/R/Cage Data Final 2016 EMV 1.20.xlsx", sheet="7.1.2016")
  str(JulyData)
summary(JulyData$Lice)

AllCages<- distinct(JulyData, Cage, Species)
  AllCages$nStart<- rep(10,nrow(AllCages))

Alive<- JulyData%>%
    filter(!is.na(Lice))%>%
    group_by(Cage, Species)%>%
summarise(nAlive=n())
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO! as far as your requirement is to count the number of rows per group, your code seems perfect.  If you want to count only unique rows you can use `n_distinct()` instead of `n()`.

Comment: As @AnilGoyal said, the code is perfectly fine if you want to know how many rows (i.e. specimens) are in your grouped data. Since you are new, I would encourage you to approach these kind of questions by looking up the man page. `?tidyverse::n()` will give you all the details.

Comment: No one can run this since the input is missing. Please read the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag for how to ask a question. In particular you need to provide a *minimal* code.,  This question has nothing to do with excel or most of the packages loaded and it depends on your directory configuration which we don't have. Strip it down to its essentials while making it reproducible.